# Gem::Installer:ExtensionBuildError

Tags: ruby, capybara-webkit

I keep hitting an error when running $ Bundle Install

> An error occurred while installing capybara-webkit (0.12.1), and
>   Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install capybara-webkit
>   -v '0.12.1'` succeeds before bundling.

Is there a way to bypass this gem and continue with the install?

Thank you!

Comment: This is just Bundler's way of saying: "Hey, I think there's something wrong with your system, cause I cannot install `capybara-webkit`".As the error messages says, check what happens when you run `gem install capybara-webkit -v '0.12.1'`

Comment: After running **gem install capybara-webkit -v '0.12.1'** I get an error notifying me that it failed to build gem native extension:

"ERROR:  Error installing capybara-webkit:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension."

Comment: so you should get a cause why the extension could not be build, maybe you are missing the required compiler or whatever, posting these erros would help to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

If `capybara-webkit` is **dependency** of one of your other gems, you can't bypass installing it, since another gem requires it to function. Otherwise, just remove / comment it out in your `Gemfile`.

According to [`capybara-webkit` Github page](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit) you've gotta setup Qt first before installing:

> capybara-webkit depends on a WebKit implementation from Qt, a cross-platform development toolkit. You'll need to download the Qt libraries to build and install the gem. You can find instructions for downloading and installing QT on the [capybara-webkit wiki](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit). capybara-webkit requires Qt version 4.8.

Comment: Thank you guys very much. I'm going to download & install QT and I'll be sure to let you know how it works out.